# How to maximize prediction for positive values (or negative values) instead of Accuracy using train function in R

Tags: r, cross-validation, prediction

I want to select and assess (using cross validation) several models in order to predict a dichotomous variable using `train` function in `caret` package, but I want to maximize prediction for positive values (or negative values) instead of global `Accuracy` maximization. Is there a way to do it using this function (`train`)?  That's because my data is very disbalanced and the command `bestTune` emphasized in global `Accuracy` for selecting the best model.